# Force submenu to be visible, when parent menu is open in jquery.menu-aim

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, magento

I am building a Magento Menu using `HoverIntent` and `jquery.menu-aim` (only second is important for this question).

I am almost done, but I have no idea, how to force first submenu entry to be visible by default, parent dropdown menu is opened. At this moment, user sees nothing and must first hover over a parent menu entry.

I tested things like making the first menu-entry to display: block using nth-child(1) via css and/or jQuery but had no success so far as I got overlapping and so on. See last commented line in my CSS.

Here is [codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emzWwg) and here is my code pasted:

**Updated** code example on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vf2bqm29/4/)

jQuery:

```
    jQuery('.nav ul').menuAim({
    activate: activateSubmenu,
    deactivate: deactivateSubmenu

});

function activateSubmenu(row) {
    var $row = jQuery(row),
        $submenu = $row.children('.nav-sub').children('ul'),
        $subbg = $row.children('.nav-sub').children('div'),
        $subh1 = $row.children('.nav-sub').children('h1');
    $row.children('a').addClass('hover');
    $submenu.css({
        display: 'block'
    });
    $subbg.css({
        display: 'block'
    });
    $subh1.css({
        display: 'block'
    });
}

function deactivateSubmenu(row) {
    var $row = jQuery(row),
        $submenu = $row.children('.nav-sub').children('ul'),
        $subbg = $row.children('.nav-sub').children('div'),
        $subh1 = $row.children('.nav-sub').children('h1');
    $row.find('a').removeClass('hover');
    $submenu.css({
        display: 'none'
    });
    $subbg.css({
        display: 'none'
    });
    $subh1.css({
        display: 'none'
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav class="nav">
  <ul class="nav-list">
    <li>
      <a href="#">menu1</a>
       <div class="nav-sub">
         <div class="nav-sub-bg"></div>
           <ul>
              <h1>Blabla</h1>
              <li>sub1</h1>
              <li>sub2</h1>
              ...
           </ul>
       </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">menu2</a>
       <div class="nav-sub">
         <div class="nav-sub-bg"></div>
           <ul>
              <h1>Blabla</h1>
              <li>sub1</h1>
              <li>sub2</h1>
              ...
           </ul>
       </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.top-menu {
    position: static;
    top: 95px;
    background: #303030;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    width: 253px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.top-menu-dropdown {
    width: 100%;
    height: 448px;
    background: rgb(65, 65, 65);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    cursor: default;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 5px !important;
}

.nav {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 258px;
    background: #ECECEC;
    padding-left: 6px;
}

.nav li {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #F0F0F0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -6px 0 0 0 #FF0000;
    box-shadow: -6px 0 0 0 #FF0000;
}

.nav a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 0;
    color: #666;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 12px;
    font-family: proxima_nova_thin;
}

.nav a.hover, .nav a:hover {
    background: #F7F7F7;
    color: #000;
}

.nav-list a:after {
    content: '>';
    float: right;
    padding-right: 8px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.nav-sub a:after {
    content: '';
}

.nav-sub ul {
    background: rgb(247, 247, 247);
    width: 736px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 264px;
    top: 0px;
    -webkit-columns: 3;
    -moz-columns: 3;
    columns: 3;
    -webkit-column-rule: 1px dotted #ddd;
    -moz-column-rule: 1px dotted #ddd;
    column-rule: 1px dotted #ddd;
    -moz-column-fill: balance;
    column-fill: balance;
    padding: 69px 5px 0 5px;
}

.nav-sub ul li {
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid;
}

.nav-sub ul li a {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: proxima_nova;
    margin-left: 6px;
}

.nav-sub ul li a:hover {
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    border-left: 6px solid red;
    margin-left: 0;
}

.nav-sub h1 {
    text-align: right;
    font-family: proxima_nova_thin;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    margin: 20px 20px;
    line-height: 1;
    width: 690px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #303030;
}

.nav-sub-bg {
    background: rgb(247, 247, 247);
    width: 746px;
    height: 424px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 264px;
    z-index: -1;
}

/*ul.nav-list li:nth-child(1) ul {display: block}*/
```

Comment: Almost made it but the menu is flickering now: http://jsfiddle.net/4zp5ze88/2/

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you looking for? you can make that 2 different ways
   by css

```
 ul.nav-list li:first-child ul {display: block}
```

by js

```
$('ul.nav-list li').first().find('ul').css('display','block');
```

in js use hover to display block just the menu you want and hide others

```
$('ul.nav-list li').hover(function(){
  $('ul.nav-list li ul').css('display','none');
  $(this).find('ul').css('display','block');
});
```

instead of all of that use css

```
 ul.nav-list li:first-child ul {display: block}
 ul.nav-list li:hover ul {display: block}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fe5sm1ww/1/)

Comment: Nope it's not working (and yes I corrected it to display hehe). When you load the page the sub-menu is not visible until you hover over an entry to the left. And I want that the first sub-menu is shown as default.

Comment: Thanks but now I have the problem that there is the described bug. When you hover over any other menu the content of the first sub-menu is still visible. (Well even on the first). To make it working you have to hover over some menus several times first. I updated my codepen.

Comment: Many thanks so far but still not fully solved. It is only working when you hover over menu1 first. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwMqVM

Comment: just delete >  like updated answer .. but look to be fair .. my answer is not a good answer .. this is another way to do that than I said .. I think using css is very simple than that

Comment: You won't see the bug when the sub-menus are always have two entrys and have same names. See forked fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vf2bqm29/1/ :(